# Android: Fill a Spinner with progress dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, progressdialog

I have a button, and when I clicked on it, I load other Activity, onCreate of this I call a method that fills a spinner with data from a Web Service.

Well, When I click at this button the screen stay "frozen" and then shows the Activity. So, I thought that it could be a good thing shows a progress dialog for user, and after gets the return of the Web Service, ends the progress dialog.

I tried use Handler, and now I'm trying to use AsyncTask, but, geting NullPointerException, because my program is filling spinner before web service get called.

```
private void fillSpinner(){
    //runWebService();
    new CallWebServiceAsyncTask().execute(null);

    mAdapter = new PlanesAdapter(this, allPlanes);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


class CallWebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlanesActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

 }

@Override

 protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {

    runWebService();
    return null;

 }

 @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    progressDialog.dismiss();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because my program is filling spinner before web service get called.

you should fill data after getting data in `onPostExecute Method`

```
 @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    mAdapter = new PlanesAdapter(this, allPlanes);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 }
```

Comment: Wow! Mistake...Thanks, Samir!

Answer (score 0):

What @SamirMangroliya suggested is correct but you even need to know where you are going wrong. When you call an AsyncTask you are asking the application to do some actions in the background which will take place in the non-UI thread. Now when you call `execute()` on your AsyncTask object the application code written in the function `doInBackground(Void... v)` runs in background and your control returns to the next statement following the call to `execute()` `[new CallWebServiceAsyncTask().execute(null)]`, which in your case is the action of filling the adapter values. These values are yet to be received from the webservice. The only place where you can be sure that your background action is completed is the function `onPostExecute(Void result)` where as suggested you can create your adapter.